# Split data frame in two disjoint sub frames based on row index

Tags: python, pandas

How can I split a dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame({'first':np.random.rand(4),'second':np.random.rand(4)},index=['foo','bar','baz','bat'])
print(df)
        first    second
foo  0.548814  0.423655
bar  0.715189  0.645894
baz  0.602763  0.437587
bat  0.544883  0.891773
```

into the two following disjoint data frames

```
        first    second
foo  0.548814  0.423655
bar  0.715189  0.645894

     first    second
baz  0.602763  0.437587
bat  0.544883  0.891773
```

by using the indices for the first data frame?

I am specifically looking for a method like

```
subDf1,subDf2 = pd.split(df,['foo','bar'])
```

where

```
print(subDf1)
   first    second
foo  0.548814  0.423655
bar  0.715189  0.645894
```

and

```
print(subDf2 )
  first    second
baz  0.602763  0.437587
bat  0.544883  0.891773
```

Comment: I think your expected subDf1 output is incorrect since it is identical to subDf2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Split Dataframe into two Dataframes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41624241/pandas-split-dataframe-into-two-dataframes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for second `DataFrame`:

```
idx = ['foo','bar']

print (df.loc[idx])
        first    second
foo  0.548814  0.423655
bar  0.715189  0.645894

print (df[~df.index.isin(idx)])
        first    second
baz  0.602763  0.437587
bat  0.544883  0.891773
```

Or [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select by labels:

```
print (df.loc[df.index.difference(idx)])
        first    second
bat  0.544883  0.891773
baz  0.602763  0.437587
```