# FutureWarning: 'DataFrame.swapaxes' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version

Tags: python, numpy

Looks like **numpy** is using deprecated function **DataFrame.swapaxes in fromnumeric.py**.

```
Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py:59: FutureWarning: 'DataFrame.swapaxes' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use 'DataFrame.transpose' instead.
  return bound(*args, **kwds)
```

I am getting this warning from the following line of code in Jupyter Notebook:

```
train, val, test = np.split(df.sample(frac=1), [int(0.8*len(df)), int(0.9*len(df))])
```

This is the structure of the dataframe I am using:
[image]

What exactly is raising this warning and what should I change in my code to get rid of this Warning?

I also found that this is currently an open issue of numpy in [github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/24889). It will be great if anybody could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swapaxes.html). If you look at the source you can see the warning is raised there. The warning also tells you how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the numpy issue on [github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/24889), this "bug" will not be fixed in numpy. The official statement is that np.split should not be used to split pandas DataFrames anymore. Instead, iloc should be used to split DataFrames as it is described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41624272/11381247).

As it looks that you are splitting the DataFrame for machine learning reasons, please be aware that there are built-in methods in many machine learning libraries doing the test/train(/validation) split for you. [Here an the example of sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).

Answer (score 0):

[`swapaxes`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swapaxes.html) has been deprecated since pandas 2.1.0 and will be removed from the API in the future.

You need to replace it with [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html#pandas.DataFrame.transpose)/[`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df.transpose()
```

Or:

```
df.T
```

Regarding the linked bug, there is unfortunately not much to be done from the user side but to wait for it to be fixed.